# Material Design md-datepicker auto-open on page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, material-design

I'm new to Material Design and I am building a page with an md-datepicker and I want to make the md-datepicker auto open on page load. How can I do this? I've searched for this matter but there are only documentations that the md-datepicker will only open on input focus. I haven't found any documentation for md-datepicker auto-open on page load yet. So far this is what I have just created, the default md-datepicker:

[image: my page]
Looking forward for your suggestions and advises. I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you add code of what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `md-datepicker` to open onLoad, I found a way to workaround by using `md-calendar`

Here is my piece of code that I added in my project:

```
<md-calendar ng-model="myDate" style="width:auto;height:auto;display:block"></md-calendar>
```

Caption:
[image: Caption]